# HTML5 Video not auto playing when using ended function

Tags: jquery, html, function, video, fullpage.js

I have a HTML5 video background of my website. Once played through it then directs to an anchor link.

This works quite nicely, my only issue is once I implement the function to direct to the anchored link, the video stops auto playing!?

The website is based on FullPage.js

Here is the code for my video function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: true,
            sectionsColor: ['#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff'],
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
            menu: '#menu',


            afterRender: function(){


                //playing the video

                $("#myVideo").play().on("ended", function load() {
                    window.location.hash="secondPage"
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the code loading in the video.

```
<video autoplay controls id="myVideo">
        <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

I tried using autoplay='autoplay' and various variations with no luck. :(

Any suggestions anyone?

Cheers

Comment: Cracked it!

**document.getElementById("myVideo").play();**
                    $("#myVideo").on("ended", function load() {
window.location.hash="secondPage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it!

```
    document.getElementById("myVideo").play(); 
$("#myVideo").on("ended", function load() { window.location.hash="secondPage"
```

Comment: That won´t assure the video to play in all cases... You should add the play event in the `afterRender` callback as I said in my answer.
Also, your second line has nothing to do with the video, but just a way to hack the URL hashing.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the available example with background videos in fullpage.js website:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/videoBackground.html

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: true,
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
            afterRender: function(){


                //playing the video
                $('video').get(0).play();
            }
        });
    });
```